# Pass special characters in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, string, special-characters

I have a text field where where the user can pass wild cards - more specific to the question they can use '%' character.

I am using ajax to get the value and send it to a PHP file. If I enter '%BA' in the text file and retrieve the value using

```
document.getElementById('textfield').value
```

This actually gets '%BA'. I am using POST method to send it to a PHP file. But the variable displays as "�" in the web browser and inserts " ° - degree small o" in the database.

I am sure there are other cases that I am not aware of as well. Is there a function in PHP to escape the special characters or any other way to get the exact string?

Edit: This may be a guess but doing `escape(document.getElementById('textfield').value)` to send the value and using `urldecode($values[3])` to retrieve the value doesn't work. Maybe it's a js to PHP problem.

Update: urldecode will not work. Read the first comment in [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php). Used the function there. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use escape in javascript i.e.

```
escape(document.getElementById('val'))
```

Answer (score 1):

while passing the value using ajax , you just encode the value with encodeURIComponent() function and use urldecode() function to decode it in the php file. This might solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could encode the characters with [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) (and maybe [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) too) before storing it in the database, and use [`urldecode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) ( and maybe [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)) to decode them before displaying to the user.

Comment: This isn't a matter of "could" and "maybe". You have to escape raw data precisely for the purpose in which you use it.

Comment: urlencode is a php function. escape is equivalent to urlencode in javascript. But still doesn't work.